# Finding the Probability Two People Will Meet

Tags: probability

Two people agree to meet at a coffee shop. They each independently pick a random moment in time between 8 a.m. and 9 a.m. and show up exactly at their selected time. But they are very impatient, and only stay for 10 minutes after when they arrive. What is the probability that they meet? Express your answer as a common fraction.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  this sort of question is best answered by drawing a picture.  Make a unit square, where the horizontal is the arrival time of one person, and the vertical the arrival time of the other.  Now draw the regions that allow for a meeting.

Comment: Even better: [Probability that two people see each other at the coffee shop](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680/probability-that-two-people-see-each-other-at-the-coffee-shop)

Answer (score 0):

It's an area in a square excluding two triangles: $1-\frac56\times \frac56=\frac{11}{36}$.